# How to do linq-to-IEnumerable-style joins in F#

Tags: linq, f#, join

I've got a project that I'm trying to convert to F#, with a fair amount of linq-to-IEnumerable style queries in it.  I'm curious what the most elegant way of doing a join of multiple lists would be in F#.  For instance if I have a bunch of C# code like the following

```
        var joinedList =
            from val1 in list1
            join val2 in list2 on val1.Key equals val2.Parent
            join val3 in list3 on val1.Key equals val3.Parent
            orderby val1
            select new {val1, val2, val3};
```

what would be the best way to translate this to F#?  I'll leave open the definition of "best", but I'm looking for something functional rather than imperative, and preferably without converting my lists to seqs and/or importing System.Linq.  Both lazy and eager solutions would be useful.  And of course reusability is key, since I have queries like this all over.  If there's any way of using workflows to make the syntax more elegant, that would be great too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in Don's blog about LINQ and the Powerpack:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150109110946/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/dsyme/archive/2009/10/23/a-quick-refresh-on-query-support-in-the-f-power-pack.aspx)

it shows off how to do LINQ join calls.  But of course that's on `seq`s and using LINQ.  He also points out that a join is like a conditional.  So I think e.g. your example is like

```
let joinedList = [
    for v1 in l1 do
    for v2 in l2 do
    if v1.Key = v2.Parent then
    for v3 in l3 do
    if v1.Key = v3.Parent then
    yield (v1, v2, v3)] |> List.sort
```

though I haven't verified it on real data.

Comment: Awesome, elegant syntax and seems even more flexible than Linq-to-objects.  I think I'm hooked!

Comment: @Dax: it is indeed more powerful than LINQ: the same core expressions work for lazy lists and any other computational expression.

Comment: Will this sort of expression transform into a single query (expression tree?) for LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: No, if you want LINQ-to-SQL, then check out the link (Don's blog about the LINQ support in the PowerPack).  @Dax was specifically asking how to do it while avoiding Linq.

Answer (score 1):

A first attempt using pipelines on a simplified version (ignore `list3`):

```
let res = list1
          |> Seq.collect (fun v1 -> Seq.filter (fun v2 -> v1.Key = v2.Parent) list2 |> Seq.map (fun v2 -> (v1,v2))
          |> Seq.sortBy (fun (x,y) -> x)
```

which will leave a `IEnumerable<Tuple<T1,T2>>`. A second collect and map would join the third list

Comment: Cool, I was able to come up with a generic Join function based off that:

        let join keySelector1 keySelector2 resultSelector list1 list2  =
          list1 |> List.collect (fun v1 -> list2 |> List.filter (fun v2 -> keySelector1(v1) = keySelector2(v2)) |> List.map (fun v2 -> resultSelector v1 v2))

But nonetheless think I'll go with the sequence expressions approach -- so elegant and powerful!